# Inserir nulo em um relacionamento com o doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Tenho uma tabela de votos e uma tabela de usuários, onde para cada voto inserido o usuário pode ou não ser identificado (relacionamento *one-to-many*).

No caso do usuário não se identificar, como faço para inserir `NULL` na *foreign key* do usuário? Tentei criar um objeto novo do usuário e realizar o insert mas não consegui.

O erro sempre retornado é o seguinte:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Portal\Model\Voto#usuario' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Portal\Model\Usuario@000000000199805b000000000453ebc2. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Portal\Model\Usuario#__toString()' to get a clue.

Answer (score 2):

O problema no caso específico da sua pergunta, é que você não está persistindo o usuário antes de persistir o voto. Você deve fazer algo assim:

```
$entityManager->persist($user);
$vote->setUser($user);
$entityManager->persist($vote);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Quando a permitir que o usuário seja nulo, basta adicionar a seguinte anotação no relacionamento do voto (acredito que `ManyToOne`) para o usuário:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema pode ser resolvido com a configuração `nullable=true` nas configurações do doctrine para sua chave estrangeira.